# String(4) "asas" is throen in the console while running artisan command laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I encountered a strange error today where the error looks like in the image:
[image]

I cloned my one of my colleague's repository and ran composer install command.
As it tried to generate optimized files, the error started popping out. After that, if I try to run any artisan command, it throws the same error text **string(4) "asas"**.
To be more precise, I already have **.env** configured.
Please help. Am I really missing something that I need to look at?

Comment: It doesn't look like an error. Seems like there is a dd() code somewhere for debugging

Comment: the little dd() always causes irritatione :-) Search for the string `asas` in the code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your colleague dumped `asas` somewhere in the code base. Probably in a place that is loaded everytime you execute a command, like a service provider.

Just search for `asas` in all files and you'll find something like:

```
dd('asas');

//or

var_dump('asas');
die;
```

Since `asas` is only the result, it may be a variable, like `dd($test);` where `asas` is the value.

If you don't find anything, search for `dd` or `var_dump`.

Comment: Thank you so much.
It was var_dump('asas') inside AuthServiceProvider for whatever reason.
Commenting that out solved the problem and I am going good with artisan now.
good day

Comment: Maybe add `dump()`to your answer next to `dd` and `var_dump` to make it complete.